# Starting an Angular Project with Fragmented Pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm completely new to Angular. I currently have a Django app that acts as a JSON-serving API (using Tastypie) and also serves up a few static pages for things like user registration, invitations, and viewing events.

Eventually, we're going to have a webapp that interacts with the Django API in all kinds of ways and makes total sense as a single page web app written in Angular (or something similar). However, as it stands right now, I just want to separate out these relatively self contained pages (mostly forms, confirmation pages, and event viewing pages) into their own app.

Since eventually everything is going to be in Angular, my thought is that I might as well start making these things in Angular, even though Angular's architecture doesn't seem very tailored to small forms and other things that will likely just be linked to from email messages.

Does it make sense to build these things out using Angular, setting up the necessary service/factory calls, making controllers for the form/event viewing pages, etc.? And if so, what's the best architectural decision in terms of modularity? Should every part of the app that "stands alone" (i.e., doesn't really interact with other parts of the app) be a separate Angular module?

Answer (score 1):

If they are literally separately loaded pages and you eventually plan to have these pages be part of a single page angular application, Than what I would do is:

1. Create angular modules that have the same variable name for all seperate pages so like var app = angular.module('blah',[])
2. I'd link all my controllers for each individual pages at the time to their specific "app" module app.controller('blahCtrl',function(){}); ...
3. You boot these modules separately on their respective pages for the
   time being
4. then when you do make the transition to moving it to one module where everything is in one page you can simply port the controllers because they will all belong to a module represented through the variable "app"